# What is the difference between NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0/1.. and nvidia.com/gpu: 0/1..?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, computer-vision, cuda, nvidia

[image]

When I changed `NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0` to 1, it's basically accessing the second's GPU's card, but changing `nvidia.com/gpu: 0` to 1 this time it's not accessing the second's GPU. What is the actual use case of `nvidia.com/gpu` numbers?

Comment: You write `nvidia.com` but the picture shows `nvshare.com`. Do you mean `nvshare.com/gpu`?

Comment: Hi paleonix, Thank you for your response. We can think in `nvidia.com` instead of `nvshare.com` because of the well known nvidia.com/gpu. This is just a key name of the device plugin. If we could use an AMD gpu card, we could use `amd.com/gpu`, similarly for nvidia we have to use nvidia.com/gpu. Here I'm using nvshare.com which use a device plugin of nvidia. This library manages GPU sharing without memory size constraints. My doubt is basically the unit of the numeric value, like (`nvidia.com/gpu: 1` or `nvshare.com/gpu: 1`, or `amd.com/gpu: 1`)

Comment: What seems pretty clear to me is that `NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` is a list of GPU IDs (also accepting some special values like `all` and `void`) that is used by Docker / the Nvidia container runtime to control which GPUs will be made available to the container. The other number seems to be the amount of GPU resources used by a k8s GPU job, see the comment in the code [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin#running-gpu-jobs). It being in `resources: limits:` should tell you that much as well. I.e. `nvidia.com/gpu: 0` should give no GPUs at all.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin#shared-access-to-gpus-with-cuda-time-slicing) you can also find information on how to specify sharing and MIG instances using `nvidia.com/gpu`. Documentation of `NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` is [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/latest/docker-specialized.html#gpu-enumeration)

Answer (score -2):

See indexing of GPU card starts with 0, i.e your first card will be indexed at 0th place. nvidea.com/gpu is typically used for resource management. This is used especial when you word with NVIDEA GPUs in a container like environment.
You can inspect the GPU information inside a container using commands like nvidia-smi to verify the GPU visibility and indices. Or if the problem persist please visit the tool's official documentation.

Comment: Hi Prakhar, Thank you for your response.
Yes, It indicates nvidia.com/gpu to NVIDIA gpu and amd.com/gpu to AMD. I'm asking about units of the 0, 1 etc like nvidia.com/gpu: 0. Let's assume cpu: "1" under the resource management. It basically 1 CPU unit is equivalent to 1 physical CPU core, or 1 virtual core  [CPU resource units](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#meaning-of-cpu). Similarly, what exact unit nvidia.com/gpu evaluates or accessing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).